# How to achieve jade template inherit in node.js

Tags: node.js, inheritance, pug

I have two jade template in the same folder,just like:

```
  |__layout.jade
  |__content.jade
```

and the layout.jade is the parent template, the content.jade will inherit from it: so in the `layout.jade`:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= title
  body
    block content
```

in the `content.jade`

```
extends layout

block content
 h1 this is frome nested template
```

however, when I run it, the inherit doesn't work, it only show the parent template's content

so what't wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include the keyword "append" in `content.jade`.

```
extends layout

block append content
  h1 this is from nested template
```

[More on this here.](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a total red herring, but I noticed your two files seem to have inconsistent indentation (at least as pasted in above).

Does it work if you correct this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and tried various answers for node.js on stack-overflow/Jade documentation.

In your app.js file check the following..

1) Check that the view engine is set to jade (now renamed pug):

```
app.set("view engine", "jade");
```

2) Set the views folder (i.e. where you've saved your template/views files):

```
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
```

3) Set layout to false:

```
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
```

4) If your using express, check that you are rendering the correct file

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("contents.jade");
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, it is ok, would you like to try a newer version of node.js and jade?